# Can't find bluetooth share neither can share via blutooth

Tags: bluetooth, user-experience

I recently got a Nokia lumia 610 from a friend . A few days ago, I tried to share songs using Bluetooth. But the share option doesn't have bluetooth. I googled it, saw many tutorials and came to know that , an app named "Bluetooth Share" is needed to do so. But in my app list i don't have it . I wanted to download it from win phone store , but there was no such app . Now, what do i do? What i so far tried is doing a system restore

Answer (score 1):

It is neither possible to share music files with Windows Phone 7.8 nor will it be possible in the future as Microsoft has stopped development and support of this plattform.

Comment: Bro , the app starts but after a few clicks , it automatically shuts down . Please give me another suggestion

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the only way as you can't share music through the Xbox Music app. There are quite a lot of other file managers in the store which might work, but I haven't tried any of those.

Comment: wait, isn't the Lumia 610 Windows Phone 7.8?

Comment: Can u please tell me the names of the apps ??

Comment: just search for "file" in the store...

Comment: But in settings>about the software shows windows phone 7.8 but downwards , the OS version shows 7.10.8862.144

Comment: I did , i downloaded files but it shows nothing , neither my photos , nor my file

Comment: sry, at first I was under the impression you're using Windows Phone 8. I updated my answer accordingly.